# how to disable url rewriting for dev mode?

Tags: url-rewrite, development

In dev mode , what's the easiest way to disable the url rewriting and find more easily the modules, class and files involved in the rendering of any page

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is change the database engine from `core_url_rewrite` to `BLACKHOLE`. Just an idea. I have no idea, what happens then, but hopefully magento recognizes that the rewrite is missing and just generates the default routes for all the things.

The alternative is to install a module like

- [CommerceBug](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-2)
- [Mgt debug bar](https://github.com/Schrank/Mgt_Developertoolbar) - my prefered version, [original](https://github.com/mgtcommerce/Mgt_Developertoolbar)
- [Magento debug](https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug)

Comment: love that Mgt debug bar. i does not work for me in front. would u know why?

Comment: nope. Sometimes it doesnt work. Most of the time I installed via modman and forgot to allow templates as symlinks. Beside of this I would think, that the block which is used to hook into the layout is missing in your template?